# center vertical without knowing the height of the container

Tags: css

Is it possible to center vertical without knowing the height of the container?

I tried display:inline-block and vertical align: middle and it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Here to check: http://jsfiddle.net/dSq2n/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="red1"></div>
    <div class="red2"></div>

    <div class="text">
        first<br>
        second<br>
        third<br>
        forth
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; left:10px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background:grey;
}

.red1, .red2{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    display:inline-block; /* ? */
    vertical-align: middle; /* ? */
    background:red;
}

.red1{
    left:0px;
}
.red2{
    right:0px; top:0px;
}
```

Comment: how you can use `vertical align` with `position absolute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute;` so using `vertical-align` is of no use, do it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dSq2n/3/)

```
.red1, .red2{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:red;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Also you need to remove `top: 0;` from

```
.red2{
    right:0px;
}
```

Explanation : What we are doing here is, using `top: 50%;` to bring the element down by 50%; but this is not perfectly centered, so we subtract `-10px;` using `margin-top` which is 1/2 of the total height of the element you want to center vertically

Comment: You are wright. Thank you.I have 3 good answers and in the same exact minute. I do not know witch one I have to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to vertically center the red boxes, yes, it is possible. But you do need to know the height of those boxes (which you do). Just use the following properties:

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -10px; // half the height of the element
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dSq2n/2/

Answer (score 1):

**Used to this**  Css

```
.red1, .red2{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    top:50%;margin-top:-10px;
  margin-top:-10px;
    background:red;
}
.red1{left:0;}
.red2{right:0;}
```

**Remove** `display inline-block`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dSq2n/5/)**

Comment: I have 3 good answers and in the same exact minute. I do not know witch one I have to choose?

Answer (score 1):

here is solution try this check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/dSq2n/6/

```
.red1, .red2{
    position:absolute;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    display:block; /* how you want to display */
    top:50%; /* give position from top */
    margin-top:-10px; /* put  minus margin from top formula is total height/2 */
    background:red;
}

.red1{
    left:0px;
}
.red2{
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `position:absolute` and then say `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: I don't understand your answer. It is already position:absolute and vertical-align: middle. What do you mean?